# How to rename and move files to new directory

Tags: file, batch-file, rename, move

I would like to rename files that are uploaded to another server from extension .txt to .txt_mvd and move to a different directory for archiving in a Windows batch mode. Can anyone help with what the windows batch script should be?

Thanks.

Comment: Have tried using Windows powershell. That should make it easy for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code

```
FOR  /R C:\your_folder %%d  IN  (*.txt)  DO  (
    ren %%d %%~nd.txt_mvd
)
```

%%d is the full file name + path
%%~nd return only the file name without the extension
Using the /R parameter, it will scan folder and subfolder

**UPDATE 1**

The following code should work as required.
I've added an IF that ignore the subfolders.

```
FOR  /R E:\your_folder\ %%d  IN  (*.*)  DO  (
    IF %%~dpd==E:\your_folder\ (
        ren %%d %%~nd.txt_mvd
    )
)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Fixed code

```
FOR  /R E:\your_folder\ %%d  IN  (*.txt)  DO  (
    IF %%~dpd==E:\your_folder\ (
        ren %%d %%~nd.txt_mvd
    )
)
```

**UPDATE 3**
Here is a more generalized and parametrized version of the script.
Change the starting parameter to your need (the first 4 lines of code).
This script first rename the files you choose (1st parameter) in your starting folder (3rd parameter), change the extension to the new one (2nd parameter), and then move the renamed files in the folder of your choice (4th parameter).

```
set Extension_of_file_you_want_to_renamne_and_move=txt
set New_extension_of_moved_files=txt_mvd

set Folder_that_contain_your_files=C:\Your_starting_folder\
set Folder_where_to_move_your_files=C:\Your_destnation_folder\

FOR  /R %Folder_that_contain_your_files% %%d  IN  (*.%Extension_of_file_you_want_to_renamne_and_move%)  DO  (
    IF %%~dpd==%Folder_that_contain_your_files% (
    IF %%~xd==.%Extension_of_file_you_want_to_renamne_and_move% (
        ren "%%~d" "%%~nd.%New_extension_of_moved_files%"
        move "%%~dpnd.%New_extension_of_moved_files%" "%Folder_where_to_move_your_files%"
        )
    )
)
```

when you change the parameter DON'T add any space.
So DON'T change the parameter like  that:

```
set Folder_that_contain_your_files = c:\myFolder      <--- WRONG, WON'T WORK, there are unneeded space
```

instead, write the parameter WITHOUT unneeded space:

```
set Folder_that_contain_your_files=c:\myFolder      <--- OK, THIS WILL WORK, there are no extra spaces
```

**UPDATE 4**
Fixed the code, I've added some quotation marks, without them the code wont works if folder name contained spaces.

```
set Extension_of_file_you_want_to_renamne_and_move=txt
set New_extension_of_moved_files=txt_mvd

set Folder_that_contain_your_files=C:\Your_starting_folder\
set Folder_where_to_move_your_files=C:\Your_destnation_folder\

FOR  /R "%Folder_that_contain_your_files%" %%d  IN  (*.%Extension_of_file_you_want_to_renamne_and_move%)  DO  (
    IF "%%~dpd"=="%Folder_that_contain_your_files%" (
    IF %%~xd==.%Extension_of_file_you_want_to_renamne_and_move% (
        ren "%%~d" "%%~nd.%New_extension_of_moved_files%"
        move "%%~dpnd.%New_extension_of_moved_files%" "%Folder_where_to_move_your_files%"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Max, for the code. I was able to rename the files but it renames all the files with ext .txt to .txt_mvd in current and all subdirectories. I only wanted to change new files that come in to the current directory and change the extension and then move it to the archive directory. Can this be changed?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, but the code didn't work right. It changed the extensions of other files including .exe to .txt_mvd. I assume that in your code, E:\your_folder\ is my current folder? Where do I mention the folder to move the changed extension files? Can you please explain the logic and where I need to put my current directory and where I need to put the archive directory?  Thank you!

Comment: @richard: sorry, there was a bug. I've fixed it

Comment: Hi Max, in this code, which is my current directory and which should be the directory to move the renamed files? Thanks.

Comment: @Richard: I've just updated the solution with a more generalized version of code, here there are explicit parameter  for starting folder, destination folder etc...

Comment: Hi @Max, I am getting error: DO was unexpected at this time. and it didn't rename or move the file. I changed the parameters like this:    set Ext=txt
set RenExt=txt_mvd

set OrigFolder=C:\Test\
set MvdFolder=C:\Test\Moved

FOR  /R %C:\Test% %%d  IN  (*.%TXT%)  DO  (
    IF %%~dpd==%C:\Test% (
    IF %%~xd==.%TXT% (
        ren "%%~d" "%%~nd.%TXT_MVD%"
        move "%%~dpnd.%TXT_MVD%" "%C:\Test\Moved%"
        )
    )
)     Is this correct or did I not change the parameters correctly? Thanks,

Comment: @richard: I've fixed the code, there was a bug on folder name with spaces

Comment: Sorry but still getting error: The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: I'm unable to fine any other bug... "it works on my machine" :-|. Did you put the backslash "\" at the end of the folders name? Without backslash it wont works.

Comment: is it possible to do the same for more than one type of file, for e.g. .DOC and .XLS with the same logic?

Comment: @Richard: the simplest way to do that for multiple file type is to create multiple batch file :-) Or, if you need to do that for  maaany different fiel type, then it's possible to further paraemtrize the batch file, and pass all the parameter "as parameter" of the command, like calling a command "c:>my_file_renamen.cmd txt txt_mvd"

Comment: thank you for your help. You've been a great help and mentor. Best regards,